# Pandas - Joining two Dataframes with Condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I am a beginner in data analytics and I am using python pandas lib to join two dataframes together.

The goal is to create a new dataframe with all the data from the second table and join the first table on the second table on 'type' to replace the numbers with the letters from the first table.
Ive already tried some merges and joins but couldnt find a solution.
Help would be appreciated.

```
#Tables were created with pd.read_csv(path, sep = '\t', encoding = 'ISO-8859-1')
#First Table

ID  type
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   D
5   E
...

#Second Table

ID  type  column2  column3 ... 
1   2     x
2   2     y
3   3     x
4   1     y
5   4     z
...
```

Comment: what's your desired output?

Comment: Welcome to SO, @frikelt!  If you put in the last merge or join you tried, it will be easier for others to help point out where you went wrong.

Comment: Is my proposed solution solved your problem. Feel free to ask any doubt

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly

```
df2.type.map(df1.set_index('ID').type)
Out[152]: 
0    B
1    B
2    C
3    A
4    D
Name: type, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
print pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['ID']).drop('type_y',axis=1).rename(columns={'type_x':'type'})
```

Output:

```
   ID type column2
0   1    A       x
1   2    B       y
2   3    C       x
3   4    D       y
4   5    E       z
```

Use `pd.merge` when you have many column in df1 and want that to be added in result, otherwise go with W-B's solution.